# I'm trying to parse with a Json file with a different arrayName than my own

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am having a problem as the JSON File I am trying to connect to has a title tag called newsItems. The file I am connecting to is the same file however it does not have the title newsItems. For example Below;

```
{
"0": {
    "image": null,
    "title": "Dhanush walks out of interview over questions on Suchi leaks ",
    "time": "03:39 pm ",
    "date": "24 Jul ",
    "content": "Actor Dhanush walked out of a television interview when the journalist asked him questions about ...",
    "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7EwWHNpiZA&amp;utm_source=inshorts&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=fullarticle "
```

Where as the title appears on this one like so.

```
{
  "newsItems":[
{
    "image": null,
    "title": "Dhanush walks out of interview over questions on Suchi leaks ",
    "time": "03:39 pm ",
    "date": "24 Jul ",
    "content": "Actor Dhanush walked out of a television interview when the journalist asked him questions about ...",
    "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7EwWHNpiZA&amp;utm_source=inshorts&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=fullarticle "
  }
```

Below is the code in my class where I am attempting to connect to this file, being hosted on free json hosting site. myjson.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            JsonObjectRequest myReq = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/z0lwn", null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                JSONArray newsItems = response.getJSONArray("newsItems");

                                for (int i = 0; i < newsItems.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject temp = newsItems.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String image = temp.getString("image");
                                    String title = temp.getString("title");
                                    String time = temp.getString("time");
                                    String date = temp.getString("date");
                                    String content = temp.getString("content");
                                    String link = temp.getString("link");

                                    newsFeed.add(new newsItem(title, content,  date, time, link, image));
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: so where is the actual problem is?

Comment: when i run my application it has not parsed. because of the array

Comment: do one thing log the value of newsItem.length() and let me know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object describing the entity of the Json, and implements 'serializable', so you can use annotation "@serialized name" and instead of volley I suggest you to use "retrofit" or OkHttp standalone with Gson. 
That way, you'll get a strong structure that is also scalable and open for changes (Json always changes over the time).